# pecl could not create lock file

Tags: php, pecl

I have problems with pecl (ubuntu 20 / xampp 8.0.1), when trying to install something I get the following message:

> WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
> downloading apcu-5.1.19.tgz ...
> Starting to download apcu-5.1.19.tgz (96,583 bytes)
> .....................done: 96,583 bytes
> ERROR: failed to mkdir /opt/lampp/lib/php/test/apcu/tests

When i try the suggested channel update command I get:

> could not create lock file

When trying to do pecl upgrade-all I get

> pear.php.net is using a unsupported protocol - This should never happen.

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything helpful yet. I'd really appreciate any suggestions how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have the permissions: You must run a command like this:

`sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net`